i tried to make a transction on sol chain between two wallet
hello i try to make a app that use solana wallet for connection when i want to make a transaction between two wallet i got this error
index-DKfn-846.js:104 Error sending message: Error: failed to get balance of account D3MJrTSEdW4TUBu9byd5mjVGMe4mHXH97VPy7NVVXSdzK: Error: 403 :  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code": 403, "message":"Access forbidden"}, "id": "5d2f34fd-b9t8r5-4a70-ba4d-15d36a6ee82f" } 

    at index-DKfn-846.js:51:23374
    at async Ek.getBalance (index-DKfn-846.js:51:23304)
    at async cT (index-DKfn-846.js:104:78014)
    at async w (index-DKfn-846.js:104:79367)

i use open api key
 {
    name: "Mainnet",
    endpoint: "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com",
    network: WalletAdapterNetwork.Mainnet,
  },

did someone have got the same big as me ?
thank to you

The public RPC APIs are heavily rate-limited to prevent abuse from users.
In your case, getting a 403 error indicates that your IP address has been blocked
As per the documentation

403 -- Your IP address or website has been blocked. It is time to run your own RPC server(s) or find a private service.

Some of the RPC providers on this list offer a free tier which you can switch to
https://solana.com/rpc

thank you i will test
